# Realtime database rules issues

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database, firebase-security

Have a DB with a coaches path. Trying to secure with rules. So read below is only allowed if they auth matches they one the user signed in with. If I test this in the rules playground it passes.

```
 {
      "rules": {
        "Coaches": {
          ".indexOn": "coachEmail",
            "$uid":{
               ".read": "$uid==auth.uid",
            }
```

But in my app it does not work get the error in logcat
Listen at /Coaches failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
What might the issue be? Could be an error in the code where the database gets queried?

```
//Query the database to get the current user
        Query query = databaseReference.orderByChild("coachEmail").equalTo(user.getEmail());
        query.addValueEventListener(new ValueEventListener() {
```

UPDATE:

```
 "rules": {
    "Coaches": {
      ".indexOn": "coachEmail",
        "$uid":{
           ".read": "auth.uid == $uid",
                    ".write": "auth.uid == $uid" 
        }
```

This passes in the rules playground

```
Type    read
Location    /Coaches/R6qhJIyLw9S6tI5llmuBhRvWWhn1
Data    null
Auth    { "provider": "anonymous", "uid": "R6qhJIyLw9S6tI5llmuBhRvWWhn1" }
Admin   false
```

Whenever I run my app I get the following error

```
Listen at /Coaches failed: DatabaseError: Permission denied
```

Not sure what the issue could be

Answer (score 1):

[Security rules do not filter your data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/core-syntax#rules-not-filters) in any way. They merely ensure that any operation your code performs against the database is allowed according to your rules.

Your code tries to load `/Coaches`, so the rules check if the user has read permission on `/Coaches`. Since they don't, the read operation is rejected.

The only read operation that is allowed by your current rules is:

```
databaseReference.child(user.getUid())...
```

---

Since you want to allow a query where the user specifies their own email address, you should update your rules to check for such a query too. As shown in the documentation on [securely querying data](https://firebase.google.com/docs/database/security/rules-conditions#query-based_rules), that'd be something like:

```
"Coaches": {
  ...
  ".read": "auth.uid != null &&
            query.orderByChild == 'coachEmail' &&
            query.equalTo == auth.token.email"
  ...
}
```

Comment: To be honest I would be happy to implement this                                                         
   "rules": {
    "Coaches": {
      "$uid": {
        ".write": "$uid === auth.uid"                                                                                                 This works in the rules playground, in my logcat for the app it says permission denied. Each coach is stored under the uid so I dont know what the issue is , the above question was trying to find a fix around it .Any time I use a wildcard value it denies permission even if i did true and true under $uid

Comment: The first half of my answer describes why your query doesn't work, and how you can load the user (based on their UID without a query). The second half describes how to make the query on the email address work securely. I'm not sure what you're asking in your comment though, so am not sure how to help further.

Comment: I would really appreciate some help as I have a project due next week and really struggling to get this implemented. I have read loads and watched videos and cant see why it isnt working

Comment: Again: the first half of my answer describes why your query doesn't work, and how you can load the user (based on their UID without a query). The second half describes how to make the query on the email address work securely. Did you try either of these parts of my answer?

Comment: Yea i tried the second part and it still  said permission denied in the log

Comment: Please show the updated code, rules and output in your question in that case. Did you also read the documentation I linked? There may always be a typo in my answer, but with the help of the documentation you should be able to figure it out.

Comment: The error in logcat now has two errors using your original answer.                                            Could not change the database journal mode of '/data/user/0/com.google.android.gms/databases/phenotype.db' from 'wal' to 'PERSIST' because the database is locked.  This usually means that there are other open connections to the database which prevents the database from enabling or disabling write-ahead logging mode.  Proceeding without changing the journal mode.
And the usual permission denied one. As I was saying id prefer the auth.uid==$uid to work but cant get it working

Comment: 1) That new error message is unrelated to the change in rules. I recommend uninstalling/reinstalling the app, to reset its state. 2) I explained why your existing `auth.uid==$uid` doesn't work for the query.